# Using icon/image instead of text for EDIT option

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart 1.5.3.
In Catalog->product I want to use edit icon/image instead of edit in text. I am not getting how to do it. Please help me where i should change this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to open

```
/admin/language/english/english.php
```

Find

```
$_['text_edit']               = 'Edit';
```

And change that text to the html you wish to use for your image, such as

```
$_['text_edit']               = '<img src="view/image/edit.png" alt="Edit" title="Edit" />';
```